# spring security + spring mvc proper application initialization

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-security-5

Beginning with spring security 5.8.9 I seem to be encountering some issues with the ordering of the configuration classes on servlet startup due to some changes they made ...

just curious how this ordering works within the confines of a web.xml .. initially I had my security config along with the root config defined as such pre spring-security-5.8.9 ..

```
<web-app version="4.0" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd">

  <display-name>MyConsole</display-name>
  <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
      com.xxx.product.console.ApplicationContextConfig,
      com.xxx.product.console.SecurityConfig
    </param-value>
  </context-param>

  <!-- Processes application requests -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
      <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>com.xxx.product.console.ServletConfig</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
 
  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

of note here my SecurityConfig class is registered at the same level as the root ApplicationContextConfig.
In 5.8.8 this works fine.
Starting in 5.8.9 I see the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFilterChains' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityFilterChain' defined in com.cybershift.ds.console.SecurityConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'securityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'A Bean named mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector of type org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector is required to use MvcRequestMatcher. Please ensure Spring Security & Spring MVC are configured in a shared ApplicationContext.'
```

So i moved the SecurityConfig to the Servlet level .. i.e

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
      <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>
        com.xxx.product.console.ServletConfig,
        com.xxx.product.console.SecurityConfig
      </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
```

with this configuration I wind up with the following error:

```
<Dec 20, 2023, 11:43:11,344 AM Alaska Standard Time> <Could not load user defined filter in web.xml: org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' available
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:874)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1358)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:309)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:283)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:283)
Truncated.
```

Any ideas what is going on here? The comments per Spring suggest that the SecurityConfig and ServletConfig(WebMvcConfig) files should be at the same application context level, but neither of these seem to work. Again this worked perfectly fine as it was in spring-security 5.8.8